# All Edittext items not displaying in scrollview

Tags: android, android-scrollview

Name, password1 field not showing up in scrollview
everything else working properly
here is my xml for it..
Made a linear layout after scrollview as it supports only one child.
Any idea what is the problem ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/retype"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gender"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Gender" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/male"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Male" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/female"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Female" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/capcha"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/typecaptcha"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Type" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Submit" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the Password field works, seems fine (I copied you XML to test it). If you use eclipse try Project>Clean. I had similar Problems.

Happy Coding

EDIT(Result):

[image]

Comment: hm, I was using `Theme.Holo`

Comment: I got it.
the orientation attribute was creating problem.

EDIT: not orientation field but layout_gravity